# can't make jar with dependencies extracted in it via ant

Tags: ant, jar

I want to build my project using `ant` but I have a small problem. My problem is that I need the output `jar` have all my `.class` and all my `jar` dependencies **extracted not zipped**.

```
<project name="ivy example" default="compress" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="resolve" description="Resolve and retrieve with ivy">
        <ivy:resolve />
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="resolve" description="compilation">
       <mkdir dir="build/classes" />
       <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes">
           <classpath refid="compile.path" />
       </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="compress"  depends="compile">
        <jar destfile="output/engine.jar" filesonly="true" update="true">
        <fileset dir="build/classes" />
        <fileset dir="lib"/>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Created-By" value="vireton"/>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="HelloIvy"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
        <echo>Building .jar file completed successfully!</echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

That code generates my `engine.jar` with the output `classes` **+** `dependencies.jar`.
I want it to generate my classes and the dependencies extracted.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did it by extracting the dependencies to a tmp directory then make a jar of both directories (src & tmp)

```
  <target name="compress"  depends="compile">
<delete file="output/engine.jar" />
    <mkdir dir="tmp" />
    <unzip dest="tmp">
        <fileset dir="lib"> 
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </unzip>
            <delete dir="tmp/META-INF" />
        <jar destfile="output/engine.jar" update="true">
        <fileset dir="build/classes" />
        <fileset dir="tmp"/>
            <manifest>
              <attribute name="Created-By" value="vireton"/>
              <attribute name="Main-Class" value="HelloIvy"/>
            </manifest>         
    </jar>  
     </target>
```

and i found an even better way to do it using

```
 <target name="compress"  depends="compile">
     <delete file="output/engine.jar" />
        <jar destfile="output/engine.jar" update="true">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar"/>
        <zipfileset dir="build/classes" />          
    </jar>  
   </target>
```

Comment: +1. Didn't know about zipgroupfileset, which is indeed simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Extract all the jars of the lib folder to some temporary folder (using the unjar task), then create the engine.jar by adding this temporary folder as a fileset.

Just like you would do it by hand.

Comment: iam new to ant scripting so i don't know how to unjar then jar as a file set can you give me a help or a reference plz

Comment: Sure. [unjar documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html), [jar documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html), [documentation for all the tasks (mkdir, etc.) and concepts (filesets, etc.)](http://ant.apache.org/manual/).

Answer (score 0):

You have your dependency jar files available as a path thanks to

```
    <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path" />
```

so the simplest way to bundle them all into your final jar would be (assuming Ant 1.8 or later)

```
  <jar destfile="output/engine.jar" filesonly="true" update="true">
    <fileset dir="build/classes" />
    <archives>
      <zips>
        <path refid="compile.path"/>
      </zips>
    </archives>
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Created-By" value="vireton"/>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="HelloIvy"/>
    </manifest>
  </jar>
```

This will read the jars directly from your ivy cache, you don't need to `retrieve` them into a local `lib` directory first.